# ViteJS: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename .vite/deps_temp -> .vite/deps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm using Vite latest version then checkout to branch which using older version. When I back to the branch where using latest version this issue happened although the app able to running.

[image]

This is my `vite.config.ts`

```
import * as path from "path"

import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    sourcemap: true
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src")
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I had a similar issue. Deleting node_modules and installing the dependencies again helped to resolve this error.

Answer (score 4):

[The solution to turn on resolve.preserveSymlinks](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/5010) works for me. Please also refer to [vite config](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-extensions).

Comment: I just rarely got that issue again. But, lemme keep your answer for reference. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

remove node_modules, pnpm-lock.yaml and reinstall dependencies works for me

Answer (score 0):

using --force when run > ## vite ##